# Quitar líneas vacías de una carga de datos y mostrar en una sola línea

Tags: php, html, mysqli, condiciones

Tengo una carga de datos que se ven de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto ocurre por la manera en que pinta el contenido pero no se como corregirlo, por mas que he investigado no encuentro aun solución, el código con el que pinto es el siguiente:

```html
$content .= '<h2 style="text-align:left;">' . "Resultado de la aplicación del Protocolo y sus recomendaciones" . '</h2>';

    $content .= '<div class="container" row d-flex justify-content-center> ';

    $sql_N3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas_n3");

    foreach ($sql_N3 as $value_N3) {
        $codigo_N3 = $value_N3['codigo'];
        $obligatorio = $value_N3['obligatorio'];

        $respuestas = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM respuestas WHERE codigo_N3 like '$codigo_N3'");

        foreach ($respuestas as $value_est) {
            $id_estado_resp = $value_est['id_estado_respuesta'];

            if ($id_estado_resp == 2 && $obligatorio == 1) {
                $show_reco = $codigo_N3;
            } else {
                $show_reco = '';
            }        
        }

        $content .= '
                    <p>' . $show_reco . '</p>                          
                    ';
    }//End while TEMA_N3

    $content .= '   
    </div>';
```

La idea es que se vea todo como un párrafo o una línea continua así:

TEM-N3-01, TEM-N3-03, TEM-N3-08, TEM-N3-11, TEM-N3-16, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso te ocurre porque por cada dato que se está pintando estás haciendo que vaya en un `<p>`, que tienen comportamiento de bloque. Una de las peculiaridades del comportamiento de bloque es que el tamaño del elemento se ajusta al 100% del ancho de su padre. Eso explica el por que no consigues hacer que se vean en el mismo párrafo.

Una solución sería hacerlo por medio de **CSS** a través de las cajas flexibles. Mediante ellas puedes hacer que todos los párrafos se alineen en el eje X, provocando que se posicionen todos en la misma línea.

```css
.caja-flexible {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Comportamiento básico</strong></p>
<div class="contenedor-normal">
  <p>Elemento 1</p>
  <p>Elemento 2</p>
  <p>Elemento 3</p>
  <p>Elemento 4</p>
</div>

<p><strong>Comportamiento con cajas flexibles</strong></p>
<div class="caja-flexible">
  <p>Elemento 1</p>
  <p>Elemento 2</p>
  <p>Elemento 3</p>
  <p>Elemento 4</p>
</div>
```

Otra manera de solucionarlo podría ser generando un **HTML** diferente desde **PHP**, abriendo una etiqueta `<p>` para cerrarla después del `foreach()`. Al estar todos los elementos dentro del mismo párrafo irán dentro de la misma línea mientras quepan.

```
$content .= '<h2 style="text-align:left;">' . "Resultado de la aplicación del Protocolo y sus recomendaciones" . '</h2>';
$content .= '<div class="container" row d-flex justify-content-center> ';

$sql_N3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas_n3");

$content .= '<p>';

foreach ($sql_N3 as $value_N3) {
    $codigo_N3 = $value_N3['codigo'];
    $obligatorio = $value_N3['obligatorio'];
    
    $respuestas = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM respuestas WHERE codigo_N3 like '$codigo_N3'");
    
    foreach ($respuestas as $value_est) {
        $id_estado_resp = $value_est['id_estado_respuesta'];
        
        if ($id_estado_resp == 2 && $obligatorio == 1) {
            $show_reco = $codigo_N3;
        } else {
            $show_reco = '';
        }        
    }
    
    $content .= $show_reco;
}

$content .= '</p>';
$content .= '</div>';
```